# Regular prime event structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, regular-language

Let $E$ be a regular prime event structure. How do you prove that $E$ has finitely many principal filters, up to isomorphism?

Comment: What is a regular prime event structure?

Comment: First of all it is a prime event structure $\mathcal{E} = (E, \leq , \#)$ where $\leq$ is a partial order and $\#$ is the conflict relation, that satisfies $a \leq b \# c \Rightarrow a \# c$, for all $a,b,c \in E$. The regularity condition is formulated as follows: the set of residuals of $\mathcal{E}[C]$, with $C$ configuration of $\mathcal{E}$ is finite up to isomorphism. Moreover there exists a natural numer $k$ such that for every configuration $C$ the events enabled by $C$ are at most $k$.

Comment: Actually I managed to prove that for every configuration $C$ of $\mathcal{E}$, the set $\{\overline{a} \in \mathcal{E}[C]^m : \overline{a} \text{ pairwise independent } \}$ is finite modulo $Aut(\mathcal{E}[C])$. Moreover its size is at most $I\binom{m}{k}$, where $I$ is the index of the regular prime event structure, independently of $C  \in \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{E})$. That answers my own question.

Comment: The question is not whether I know or not the Thiagarajan conjecture but how many people on this site will know about it. When you ask a question, please give all relevant definitions (possibly by giving a link). I suggest you to edit your question to include your comments (and possibly the statement or a relevant link to the Thiagarajan conjecture if you think this is relevant).

Comment: By the way, Thiagarajan's conjecture is false.